# How to replace empty instance in list with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace empty instances `''` with `'.'` in list `compare`:

```
compare = ['ŋsbluː', 'mən', '', 'blˈyːt', '', 'ʔˈɛs']
compare = [w.replace('', '.') for w in compare]
```

Output: `['.ŋ.s.b.l.u.ː.', '.m.ə.n.', '.', '.b.l.ˈ.y.ː.t.', '.', '.ʔ.ˈ.ɛ.s.]'`

But I want: `['ŋsbluː', 'mən', '.', 'blˈyːt', '.', 'ʔˈɛs']`

Comment: `print([i if i else "." for i in compare])` ?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `replace` on the individual elements in the list. You can accomplish the desired effect by filtering through the list:

```
compare = ['ŋsbluː', 'mən', '', 'blˈyːt', '', 'ʔˈɛs']
compare = ["." if x == "" else x for x in compare]
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `x == ""` instead of `if not x`

Comment: In the end, it all boils down to `[x if x else '.' for x in compare]` -> `[x or '.' for x in compare]`

Comment: Yeah, that's a much cleaner way to do it. The user specifically said empty string, but it seems unlikely that they'd encounter `None` or other false-y values in this context.

Answer (score 2):

`compare = [i or '.' for i in compare]`

Answer (score 1):

What you really mean is `compare = ['.' if w == '' else w for w in compare]` rather than `replace` which would replace every zero-length substring in your code.

But then you don't really need a list comprehension because it could also be in-place.

```
for i, x in enumerate(compare):
    if x == '':
        compare[i] = '.'
```

Comment: Isn't this identical to what he has in his question?

Comment: @user3483203 sorry, typo in editing